# I am unable to get rosmsg show num

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

In the above tutorial  whenever i trying to get rosmsg show  num i will face this error in bash

```
**glv13@GLV-Inspiron-N4010:~/catkin_ws/src/my_first_package$ rosmsg show num
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rosmsg", line 35, in <module>
    rosmsg.rosmsgmain()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 754, in rosmsgmain
    sys.exit(rosmsg_cmd_show(ext, full, command))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 621, in rosmsg_cmd_show
    found_msgs = list(rosmsg_search(rospack, mode, arg))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 565, in rosmsg_search
    for p, path in iterate_packages(rospack, mode):**
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 541, in iterate_packages
    package_paths = _get_package_paths(p, rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 554, in _get_package_paths
    results = find_in_workspaces(search_dirs=['share'], project=pkgname, first_match_only=True, workspace_to_source_spaces=_catkin_workspace_to_source_spaces, source_path_to_packages=_catkin_source_path_to_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 143, in find_in_workspaces
    source_path_to_packages[source_path] = find_packages(source_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 89, in find_packages
    packages = find_packages_allowing_duplicates(basepath, exclude_paths=exclude_paths, exclude_subspaces=exclude_subspaces, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 150, in find_packages_allowing_duplicates
    xml, filename=filename, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 552, in parse_package_string
    _get_node_attr(node, 'email')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 727, in _get_node_attr
    raise InvalidPackage('The "%s" tag must have the attribute "%s"' % (node.tagName, attr))
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage: The "maintainer" tag must have the attribute "email"**
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301669/i-am-unable-to-get-rosmsg-show-num/) by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at the error message on the last line. Somewhere in your catkin workspace, there is a malformed `package.xml`. The maintainer line should look like this:

```
<maintainer email="martin.guenther@example.com">Martin Günther</maintainer>
```

... but the `email` attribute is missing, i.e. it looks like this, which is wrong:

```
<maintainer>Martin Günther</maintainer>
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on 2018-08-27**:
Thanks **Mr. Martin Gunther** for your suggestion. It's working fine now, what I did is I wrote "gmail" instead of "email" in maintainer attribute. once again THANK YOU.